# Change name of test method in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

Is there a way to change the name of the `method` that PHPUnit uses to look for tests? I would like to change the default `test` prefix to be use a BDD style and begin with `it` instead.

My search has only turned up ways to change the name of the file with the phpunit.xml config,

```
<directory prefix="test-" suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some digging and I found in `Framework\TestSuite.php`:

```
public static function isTestMethod(ReflectionMethod $method)
{
    if (strpos($method->name, 'test') === 0) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    // @scenario on TestCase::testMethod()
    // @test     on TestCase::testMethod()
    return strpos($method->getDocComment(), '@test')     !== FALSE ||
           strpos($method->getDocComment(), '@scenario') !== FALSE;
}
```

So either the name starts with `"test"` or it has an annotation of `@test` or `@scenario`. I've confirmed the annotation works.

As you can see there is no configuration passed into this function so I don't think you can configure a custom prefix.

Comment: Too bad, I was hoping to avoid annotations as well. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Here is a good example of using annotations: https://github.com/laracasts/Flexible-Flash-Messages/blob/master/app/tests/ExampleTest.php